# Integrating exponential with large complex argument sends the result to zero

Tags: integration, limits, complex-numbers, indefinite-integrals, approximation

I am evaluating the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} a(t) exp(-i \omega t) dt,$$

with a being a function of t.

The textbook says to estimate the integral in the limits of $\omega >> 1$ and $\omega << 1$. It says that, in the limit of $\omega >> 1$, "the exponential in the integral oscillates rapidly, and the integral is small" (i.e., negligible).

I don't understand the meaning of this comment. I know that $exp(i\omega t) = cos(\omega t) + i sin(\omega t)$, but I don't get how the integral would go to zero.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma - see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma  The exponential oscillates so rapidly that the integral vanishes in the limit, due to cancellation.

Comment: Excellent comment by Tom Dickens. Besides, do you know that your integral as a function of $\omega$ is "the" **Fourier Transform** of function $a$ ?